# Can't use function return value in write context on list function

Tags: php, image-uploading

On running the below code it results an error for me like

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
>   /home/site/public_html/administrator/blog_manage.php on line 24

line 24 is the `list` function

```
if($manage=="add_blog")
    {
            $titile=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titile']);
            $news=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['news']);
            $date=date("d F Y");
            $radio=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['r']);
            list(mysql_real_escape_string($d),mysql_real_escape_string($m),mysql_real_escape_string($y))=explode(" ",$date);
            $sql="insert into blog (name,day,month,year,date,content)
            values('$titile','$d','$m','$y','$date','$news')";
            $query=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

            $memberID = -1;
            $sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
            $rs = mysql_query($sql);
            if($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
            {
            $memberID= $row['LAST_INSERT_ID()'];
            }

    if($radio=='image'){
    if(isset($_FILES['image']))
    {
         $baseName = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
         $ext=strrchr($baseName,".");
        if(isset($baseName) && strlen(trim($baseName)) > 0)
        {
        $filenameToStore = $memberID."blog".$ext;
        $uploadfile = "../blog/images/". $filenameToStore;
        //echo $uploadfile;

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
            {


                $sql = "UPDATE blog
                    SET image= '$filenameToStore',url='NIL'
                    WHERE id = $memberID";
            mysql_query($sql) or die(" Error # 5156");

            } 
        }
```

}

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually pass the variables to list(), you can't wrap them in a function.

You need to do:

```
list($d,$m,$y)=explode(" ",$date);
```

You can escape them later.

Also, you need to be using mysqli or PDO, mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: escape them later means?

Comment: Do it later in the code...obviously you want to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on each of them, so just do it the line below. E.g. `$d = mysql_real_escape_string($d)`.